# SQL stored procedure to pass date value in months/years

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on a C#/WPF application and connecting it with SQL.

I am trying to write a stored procedure in SQL that takes a selected date and converts it into (month, year) so at the time of executing, for example I put 1 for January and 2018 for the year and it will display the total sales for 2018 (that occurred in any given month in this case, January)

Ultimately in C#, the user will choose any given month from a comboBox, same for the year and click show sales and it should display using the stored procedure.

So far, I have this in SQL

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[salesForSelectedMonth] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    
    @date date
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    SELECT SUM (TotalPrice) AS TOTAL_SALES, YEAR([TruckRental-PB].RentDate) AS year, MONTH([TruckRental-PB].RentDate) AS month
    FROM [TruckRental-PB]
    WHERE MONTH(@date) = MONTH([TruckRental-PB].RentDate)
    AND YEAR(@date) = YEAR([TruckRental-PB].RentDate)
    GROUP BY [TruckRental-PB].RentDate;

    
    
END
```

The issue is this is only allowing for putting a date then it shows the total sale

what I want is to get from C# the month (data type int), year (int) pass it to SQL proc to produce total sales

This is the logic I have so far (getting a datepicker value and passing it to the above proc) but getting an error still

```
public static int monthlySales (DateTime date)
{
    using (Data_Context ctx = new Data_Context())
    {
        int sales = int.Parse(ctx.TruckRentalPbs.FromSqlRaw("salesForSelectedMonth", date).FirstOrDefault().ToString());
        return sales;
    }
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: ''FromSqlRaw' or
> 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a
> query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the
> method to perform the composition on the client side.'

**UPDATE**

I was able to pass month and year as int inside stored procedure however now it is showing the year as 1905 - any idea why?

```
-- Fetch matching month and year only
    WHERE 
        @month = MONTH([TruckRental-PB].RentDate)
    AND 
        @year = YEAR([TruckRental-PB].RentDate)

    GROUP BY YEAR([TruckRental-PB].RentDate), MONTH([TruckRental-PB].RentDate)
```

[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM79T.png)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Looks like MS SQL Server code?)

Comment: Have you tried what the error message is asking you to do?

Comment: @jarlh yes MS SQL

Comment: @ChristofWollenhaupt yup, still getting error so trying to figure out how to pass month/year instead of date

Comment: Side note: this query would be much more efficient if you used date ranges `WHERE  = [TruckRental-PB].RentDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@date), MONTH(@date), 1) AND [TruckRental-PB].RentDate < DATEADD(month, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@date), MONTH(@date), 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't really related to the type of parameter you pass, at least not your first problem. Your code

```
int sales = int.Parse(ctx.TruckRentalPbs.FromSqlRaw("salesForSelectedMonth", date).FirstOrDefault().ToString());
```

can't work this way. Entity Framework needs to map the result from FromSqlRaw to the entities it knows. But here you are returning an unknown result set where it doesn't know anything about its structure.

The workaround for this is to turn the result from EF into a memory bound collection and then use regular LINQ queries for the remaining code:

```
int sales = int.Parse(ctx.TruckRentalPbs.FromSqlRaw("salesForSelectedMonth", date).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault().ToString());
```

Then you can change the parameters by replacing the date parameter with two INT parameters and pass both into the query.